# How to match times with days using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

It's the first time for me to put a question here and I'm a beginner in Python. I'd match times (hours and minutes) with days from a text. I wrote this expression for that:

```
(([0-9]+.?[0-9]+(a|p)m)[(Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day]?)
```

However, it matches times only without days. Can you help me please what the wrong with that expression is?
Many thanks

Comment: For regexes it i prudent to post the _text_ you are looking into as well. How would we test otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within `[(Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day]?`, because as stated in [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

> Only parentheses can be used for grouping. Square brackets define a
>   character class, and curly braces are used by a quantifier with
>   specific limits.

So you need to change square brackets for parentheses:

```
((Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day)?
```

Your final regex should look like this:

```
(([0-9]+.?[0-9]+(a|p)m)((Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day)?)
```

I make some changes to improve it a little bit:

```
((\d{1,2}:?\d{1,2}(a|p)m)((Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day)?)
```

Where:

- `\d` its the same as `[0-9]`.
- `{1,2}` means that the preceding token should be present 1 or 2 times.

As a tip, you could use https://regex101.com to build your regular expressions and test them in place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Itried it but it didn't work with my Mac. So, If I want to match time and day from this sentence: (Can you tell me the name of a movie which starts at 6.10pm on Thursday the 16th of August please?), it still matches time only without day.